# curl: (7) Failed to connect to get.sdkman.io port 443: Network is unreachable

Tags: macos, sdk, sdkman

I am trying to install sdkman on my mac. I simply copy and paste the curl command that is given on the website "curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash" but when i do I keep getting the error message mentioned above in the title.

I remove the -s to get the error message so the command looks like this
"curl "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash"

can anyone help?

Comment: You have some sort of network connectivity or routing problem; you'll have to troubleshoot your network connection to find out what's wrong. If you need help with that, [Superuser](https://superuser.com) is a better place to ask about things like this (but your ISP may be even better, if they're competent).

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar issue with my Mac, running the original install command from the Sdkman website gives me the error, curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.sdkman.io
 
 'curl --fail --location --progress-bar "$download_url" > "$sdkman_zip_file"': command failed with exit code 6. Were you able to find a solution for this @Emmanuel

Comment: same issue here...did you manage to solve this?

Comment: for some reason `curl` was failing due to certificate problem, I downloaded installation file and in all curl calls added parameter --ssl-no-revoke it will help with install but after that sdkman itself cannot connect to it server probably due to the same issue, and think it is in the offline mode..

Comment: so in the sdkman directory you have to edit config property `sdkman_insecure_ssl` to enable insecure connections